# Need advice about a vague question on postdoc position search and post thesis submission dilemma

Tags: phd, application, postdocs

I am a veteran PhD student who have just submitted my PhD thesis and am waiting for my defense. The defense is to be scheduled for the end of the year (end of November). Due to lack of proper foresight and getting overwhelmed during the last year of PhD work, I have no option for my next career move.

I will be getting supported by my advisor till I defend my thesis. However, I am worried that I don't have enough time to get a position anywhere by the time I defend. I have started looking for positions and applying for them.

My advisor says that due to the lack of funds, she won't be able to keep me as a postdoc after my defense but she can support me for 4 months into the next year as a research assistant till I get some position. At the moment, I am submitting my papers, working on remaining projects. Also, would apply for fellowships.

My question is very vague, and is borderline panicked rant, and I apologize for it.

How should I effectively utilize my remaining months before my defense?
Is it possible to get and start a position within 4-5 months?

I am an international student and will secure a work visa after my PhD defense. So, there shouldn't be any visa issue.

Comment: You mention (the lack of) visa issues. Are you interested in positions in a particular country only?

Comment: If your defense is the end of November and you have support for 4 months of next year (through April?) then it seems you have a lot more than 4-5 months to find a job. You already said you've started looking and applying - good - what else can we suggest you do?

Comment: What kind of area is your interest in? Which job profile could you consider?